# Calculating the expectation of function that depends on original random variable and smallest order stat

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

I'm calculating the MSE of a particular statistic and I'm ultimately stuck on deriving the following: $$E\left[\sum_{i=1}^n(X_i-X_{n:1})^2\right]$$

More specifically, to calculate the expectation $E[g(x_i, x_{n
;1})],$ would I need to use the joint pdf for $X$ and $X_{n:1}$? I don't believe I know how to derive this. Also, I am assuming that the two arguments for the function $g$ are not independent, which may or may not be correct...

Comment: Note that
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[(X-Y)^2\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2 + Y^2 - 2XY\right]
 = \mathbb{E}\left[X^2\right] + \mathbb{E}\left[Y^2\right] - 2\mathbb{E}\left[XY\right]
$$
so
$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{E}\left[\sum_{k=1}^n \left(X_i-X_{(1)}\right)^2\right]
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i^2+X_{(1)}^2 - 2X_iX_{(1)}\right]\\
 &= \sum_{k=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[X_i^2\right]
  + n \mathbb{E}\left[X_{(1)}^2\right]
  - 2 \mathbb{E}\left[X_{(1)} \sum_{k=1}^n X_i\right]
\end{split}
$$
I am not sure if that last term is easier term-by-term or as a whole sum...

Comment: Right, thanks. Still, as you mention, I'm not sure how to deal with the last term...

Comment: What is the parent distribution?

Comment: The last term could be expressed $\displaystyle 2\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(1)}\sum_{k=1}^n X_{i} \right] = 2\mathbb{E}\left[X_{(1)}\sum_{k=1}^n X_{(i)} \right] = 2\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbb{E}[X_{(1)}X_{(i)}]$

Comment: @StubbornAtom By parent distribution, do you mean the distribution of $X$? The pdf is $f(x)=\sigma^{-1}e^{-(x-\mu)/\sigma}$ where $x>\mu$.

Comment: Since you do not write the actual question, it could be that this is not what you are actually asked to find.